# How to filter ggplotly object

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I have the following ggplot object:

```
    f1=structure(list(data = structure(list(hh = c("School 1", "School 1", 
"School 1", "School 1", "School 1", "School 2", "School 2", "School 2", 
"School 2", "School 2", "School 3", "School 3", "School 3", "School 3", 
"School 3", "School 4", "School 4", "School 4", "School 4"), 
    Group = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), levels = c("Prefer not to\nanswer", 
    "University", "G10-G12", "G2-G9", "K-G1"), class = "factor"), 
    n = c(69L, 85L, 309L, 5L, 85L, 84L, 143L, 499L, 12L, 252L, 
    30L, 87L, 278L, 9L, 155L, 1L, 5L, 61L, 7L), freq = c(0.124773960216998, 
    0.15370705244123, 0.55877034358047, 0.00904159132007233, 
    0.15370705244123, 0.0848484848484849, 0.144444444444444, 
    0.504040404040404, 0.0121212121212121, 0.254545454545455, 
    0.0536672629695885, 0.155635062611807, 0.497316636851521, 
    0.0161001788908766, 0.277280858676207, 0.0135135135135135, 
    0.0675675675675676, 0.824324324324324, 0.0945945945945946
    ), N = c(553L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 990L, 990L, 990L, 
    990L, 990L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
    74L), Propotion = c(0.12, 0.15, 0.56, 0.01, 0.15, 0.08, 0.14, 
    0.5, 0.01, 0.25, 0.05, 0.16, 0.5, 0.02, 0.28, 0.01, 0.07, 
    0.82, 0.09), Percent = c("12%", "15%", "56%", "1%", "15%", 
    "8%", "14%", "50%", "1%", "25%", "5%", "16%", "50%", "2%", 
    "28%", "1%", "7%", "82%", "9%"), order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L)), layers = list(<environment>), scales = <environment>, 
    mapping = structure(list(x = ~Group, y = ~n, N = ~N, fill = ~Group, 
        Percent = ~Percent), class = "uneval"), theme = structure(list(
        line = structure(list(colour = "black", linewidth = 0.5, 
            linetype = 1, lineend = "butt", arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), rect = structure(list(fill = NA, colour = NA, 
            linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
            colour = "black", size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
            angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), title = NULL, aspect.ratio = NULL, axis.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = 11, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(3.5, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 3.5, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.bottom = NULL, axis.title.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 1, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 3.5, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.y.left = NULL, axis.title.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 0, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 3.5), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = "black", size = 10, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = NULL, 
            debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(3, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 3, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.bottom = NULL, axis.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 3, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.y.left = NULL, axis.text.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 3), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(colour = "black", 
            linewidth = 0.5, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, 
            arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.ticks.x = NULL, axis.ticks.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.y = NULL, axis.ticks.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.y.right = NULL, axis.ticks.length = structure(3.5, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL, axis.ticks.length.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y.right = NULL, 
        axis.line = structure(list(colour = "black", linewidth = 0.5, 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = "square", arrow = FALSE, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.line.x.bottom = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, axis.line.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.line.y.right = NULL, legend.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
        "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.spacing = structure(14, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, 
        legend.key = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.key.size = structure(15.4, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, 
        legend.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = structure(0.857142857142857, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "none", 
        legend.direction = NULL, legend.justification = c("left", 
        "center"), legend.box = NULL, legend.box.just = NULL, 
        legend.box.margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
        "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.box.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.box.spacing = structure(14, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.border = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(7, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major = NULL, panel.grid.minor = NULL, 
        panel.grid.major.x = NULL, panel.grid.major.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid.minor.x = NULL, panel.grid.minor.y = NULL, 
        panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), plot.title = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = "bold", colour = NULL, size = structure(1.14285714285714, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 7, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.title.position = "panel", plot.subtitle = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.857142857142857, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 7, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.785714285714286, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(7, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption.position = "panel", plot.tag = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = "bold", colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 0.7, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = c(0, 1), plot.margin = structure(c(7, 
        7, 7, 7), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.background = structure(list(
            fill = "grey80", colour = NULL, linewidth = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), strip.background.x = NULL, strip.background.y = NULL, 
        strip.clip = "inherit", strip.placement = "inside", strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.857142857142857, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.x.bottom = NULL, 
        strip.text.x.top = NULL, strip.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.y.left = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = NULL, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, margin = NULL, 
            debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.y.right = NULL, strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(3.5, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(3.5, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2"))), class = c("theme", "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), 
    coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, 
    labels = list(fill = "A", x = "", y = "Number of Respondents", 
        title = "", N = "N", Percent = "Percent")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

I want to convert it to a plot_ly object using the ggplotly function and filter the data based on the button input:

```
f1 <- ggplotly(f1, tooltip = c("n", "Percent", "N")) |> 
        add_trace(x = ~Group, y = ~n, 
                              transforms = list(
                                list(
                                  type = "filter",
                                  target = ~hh,
                                  operation = '=',
                                  value = unique(f1.data$hh)[1]))) |> 
        layout(updatemenus = list(
              list(
                type = 'dropdown',
                active = 2,
                buttons = plotly.buttons)))
```

The buttons work and shows the unique groups but the filtering part does not work. I specifically want to use the ggplotly function. What is correct way to filter plot based on button input?

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` the libraries and the code you used. It looks like you did a `dput` call on the plot. Additionally, where's the code for `plotly.buttons`? Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).  In the mean time, [see if this Q & A helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77629529/how-to-change-plots-with-plotly-button)